# Maple does not recognize an integral as a special function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

## Maple does not recognize an integral as a special function:

Writing in Maple:

```
with(inttrans); #not necessary
with(MathematicalFunctions); #not necessary
int(t^(z-1)*e^(-t), t = 0 .. infinity); assume(Re(z)>0);
```

This is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Definition). But apparently, Maple doesn't recognize it?!

The Maple *FunctionAdvisor* provides information on mathematical functions in general, but what if I don't know that this specific expression is the Gamma function?

**Is there a way that Maple will recognize a specific expression as a special function?**

Mathematica does it by default:

```
In[1]=  Integrate[t^(z - 1) E^(-t), {t, 0, Infinity}] /; Re[z] > 0
Out[2]= ConditionalExpression[Gamma[z], Re[z] > 0] /; Re[z] > 0
```

Comment: The code `/; Re[z] > 0` is no-sense.

Answer (score 2):

What will help here is to use the correct Maple syntax for raising the base of the natural logarithm to some exponent.

In Maple, the name `e` is unassigned by default and has no special meaning. You have mistakenly used `e^(-t)` when what's needed is `exp(-t)` instead. That is a common usage mistake.

Perhaps you intended this:

```
int(t^(z-1)*exp(-t), t = 0 .. infinity) assuming Re(z)>0;

                                       GAMMA(z)
```

Note that Maple will pretty-print its so-called 2D Output so that a function call to `exp` displays like a power of **e**, but that **e** is shown with an upright Roman **e**. Maple pretty-prints the regular name ***e*** in italic, like for other variable names that are otherwise unassigned and not language keywords.

Comment: Many thanks! I mistakenly wrote `e^(-t)` instead of `exp(-t)`.